# Emulators for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I want to get a few emulators for Android Studio so I can test my apps, but I can't  find out where to get them and how to install them. Thanks for the help!

Edit: Thank you both I got it working!

Comment: No need to install..You can just use them..In android studion You have to first create an AVD by going to the AVD manager..While crating a new AVD you can select an emulator that you want..Once created start the emulator..

Comment: And in the Eclipse first run you application. Once the avd is not there that is asked you to create. Then select that and run.

Comment: Here is a Link that shows you how to do that..http://www.donnfelker.com/android-studio-setting-up-an-emulator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
1 - SDK Manager. Here you can install android system image.
2 - AVD Manager. Here you can define own Android Virtual Device. (First you need to install android system image via SDK Manager and then define you device based on that image)

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you got the emulators working so you can test your apps.  You also might want to try the virtual machine approach as you may find a significant speed improvement over the emulators that come with the SDK.

Probably the easiest way to get started with testing your apps on a virtual machine is by using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).  There is a selection of machines with different APIs, and the Genymotion launcher integrates with adb (i.e., the connection to Eclipse/AS) and wraps the VM with GPS/telephony/camera simulation.  Available for Mac/Win/Linux.

Comment: nice suggestion Paul, but the Genymotion is a paid thing
is there any similar solution that serves us free of cost??
i want to test my app on an emulator other than the one that comes with AS, the one with AS is too damn slow !

Comment: If you create an account at Genymotion and log in, you'll be able to download Genymotion and use the default "personal use" license. That said, the new website does seem to make this process a little less-obvious, leading me to believe they may be starting to move away from a free tier. Other options that you might want to consider are RemixOS and the Android-x86 project. These run nicely in VirtualBox or on real devices, such as old laptops. However, if you're doing a lot with h/w sensors, location, etc., and are fed up with slow emulators, you should probably invest in a real device.

Comment: thanks paul, i do have a real device but right now i am learning android development and i dont wanna upload my App every time i make a change to my device and test. and one more thing is with genymotion can i check for the logs which the device generates?

Comment: Yes, the logs from your Genymotion device will show up in Android Studio just like they do for an emulator or real device. You can also use `adb logcat` to see the device's logcat via command line, without having to go through Studio.