# Android - Standalone emulators for testing apps

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know that Android studio comes with an Emulator for testing apps. but this Emulator is too damn slow and never runs on my machine.
so i was checking for alternatives like if at all there is a standalone emulator which i can install on my system and upload my APKs and test. It is good if this emulator tool kit also shows the logs. 
I just want something to test my Apps without the Emulator that comes with Android SDK.

While i was browsing SO i bumped into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679690/emulators-for-android-studio) here check for the comment that Paul Ratazzi has written, (second comment) this one is a paid solution so i did not dig into it much.

Answer (score 1):

Genymotion is free for individuals. So you can use it unless its commercials and better than Emulators.

Comment: is Genymotion a standalone emulator?

Comment: No. You have to install virtual box along with genymotions and has to download the different emulators as you preferred. It also available in single bundle.

Comment: i have now installed the virtual box and genymotion, have downloaded a device and all set. but now when i run the device i see a back screen with all the navigation , camera buttons etc but i done see the home screen of the device. and when i check my Network adapters i see 2 new adapters named, Virtual box host is seen, what is my way forward here?